# SIGFAULT with one thread - does it affect other existing threads?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

If my application runs 'x' number of threads, and if there are any one of them does the nasty memory corruption, and hence SIGFAULT occurs!!!. Does it affect other threads also ?

Comment: BTW you shouls look at some of your questions and accept some answers (the green tick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you handle it, then yes, it kills the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

offcorse it will effect all other threads.
see you are running x number of threads with your application it means you have created one process having x number of threads now when anyoone threads gets segmention faults & you cant able to handle that then it will kill your main process ...indirectly all ur threads will also close....!!!